# Read X window property of non client area

Tags: window-manager, x

How to read property of X window non-client area (window manager's window)? I set X property by `XChangeProperty` in my C program. When using `xprop` and selecting non client area (I mean: titlebar of the window) by mouse, properties of window created by my application aren't displayed.
I tested both cases. When using `xprop 8s name_of_non_registered_property` and `xprop 8s name_of_registered_property` message is different, so I correctry create XAtom.

I test xprop only on Plasma5.15 (KWin working under X.org)

I'm mixing GTK+2 and XCB (or XLib) code. When using `XListProperty`, `XGetAtomName` on elements from previous call to previous function and result of `XGetAtomName` put to `puts` (C stdlib), name of my atom is visible. Maybe GTK mess, when invoking main loop first time? I realize the window before add my property to it.

I think, that rather programming problem than system.

```
> xwininfo -all -root
....
0xba00001 "program": ("program" "Program")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
    1 child:
    0xba00002 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +9+9
...
>xprop -id 0xba00001
 WM_CLASS(STRING) = "program", "Program"
 WM_COMMAND(STRING) = { "program" }
 _NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0xba00002
 _KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 29562975
 WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0xba00001
 _NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 25223
 WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "pl_PL.UTF-8"
 WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "linux-rvnb"
 WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
                 program specified size: 10 by 10
>xprop -id 0xba00002
>
```

Comment: maybe you're not selecting the right window -- wm decorations like titlebars may themselves be subwindows of the the frame window you set your properties on. Anyways, post something reproducible; your question is not clear.

Comment: Should I attach C code? That's not stack overflow.

Comment: You should add the output of the two xprop commands.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like an XY problem. The non-client parts (e.g. title bar) are managed by the WM, they will be different for different WMs, so relying in any properties there will break as soon as the WM changes. Therefore I'm not surprised trying to get and set them runs into trouble (but what exactly happens probably also depends on the WM). **What exactly are you trying to achieve by using properties on non-client areas?** I'm pretty sure that whatever it is, there's a correct alternative way to do it.

Comment: I will write app-integrated macro recorder. Possible a new design of such programs :-) . App register to window manager it's supports recording macro by setting atom on window and window manager will display dropdown menu with macro-related functions. User could click on first window, select start recording a new macro, set name. I next step he click on other window's titlebar and select attach to macro. Window manager will send XID or other information to daemon, which next asks app for window data (strings representing the state of window).

Comment: So why not store the properties on the main window of the program, where all the other properties are?

Comment: I must read GTK2 documentation again. Can WM access this property by only getting an only child of WM frame?

Comment: I have no idea what GTK2 does; I am only used to X in general. While a WM *can* reparent an application window to draw decorations, it doesn't *have to*, and there are WMs that don't. So far, with all WMs I've used, I've only ever seen properties on the toplevel windows of the application (main window, popups etc.), and never on the WM controlled non-client window. You can check with `wminfo -tree -root` and `xprop -id some_win_id`.

Comment: To quote the Xlib programming manual, chapter 12: "It is a fundamental principle of client-window manager communication that a general client should not care which window manager is running or, indeed, if one is running at all. The choice of window manager is up to the user or perhaps the system administrator, not the client." "Once the client has created one or more top-level windows but before it maps them, it must place properties on **those windows** to help the window manager manage them effectively." (my emphasis)

Comment: @dirkt: This topic go into programming categories. I have one question. I must realize (display window) to get one's XID. I think I could realize it, but not display, and set properties before displaying. Am I right? I will try this tommorow and maybe select your response as solution or add this solution to problem description or as my own solution. I doubt if there's a good reason to not remove this question because it's rather about programming.

Comment: All of this is now going beyond the original question (which may be moot at this point), and is probably better suited to a series of question on stackoverflow, but: It's the *application program* that realizes the windows it owns. It's not the job of anyone else to realize windows for the application program. I'm not sure how your macro recorder is designed, and how it is supposed to attach to an application, but unless it lives in the part of the application where the toplevel window(s) are created and realized, you may have to think about a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command prints all childrens:

```
xwininfo -all -root
```

Not all windowmanagers use the root window to show the backround. Clicking on a non client area will show infos about the window that displays the background. To show infos about the root window use:

```
xprop -root
```

If you correctly set an atom, `xprop` can read it. The format part in your `xprop` command is not necessary:

```
xprop name_of_registered_property
```

You might have to traverse all children to find the window with your atom.

If you're not coding the wm, you should ignore the titlebars. They are wm internals, not a client and they are probably not registered for events.

Comment: Thanks. By writing non-client area I mean titlebar.

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Since the titlebar is createt by your windowmanager, you should add which wm/de you use too.

Comment: I will add some info: Use xwininfo -all -root, read the id of child of window using parent's window title. Use xprop -id hexadecimal number present in xwininfo output